# JqxCombo values not setting from ajax result - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jqxwidgets, jqxcombobox

I have been trying to use JqxWidgets with Vue.js, the basic idea here is that we may have multiple ComboBox in the form and just calling the ComboBox template and providing the ajax call, it should get and set to that particular combobox.

So until now I have this

```
<template>
    <JqxComboBox ref="core_combobox" :width="`100%`" :height="25" 
                 @change="onChange($event)" :source="source" :selectedIndex="0" :displayMember="'label'" :valueMember="'value'">
    </JqxComboBox>
</template>

<script>
    import JqxComboBox from "./jqx-vue/vue_jqxcombobox.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        JqxComboBox
    },
    props : {
        comboDataSource : String
    },
    methods: {
        // Add here all used callbacks and/or events
        onChange: function (event) {
             if (event.args) {
                    let item = event.args.item;
                    if (item) {
                        alert(item.value)
                    }
                }
        },

        getComboSource : function (){
         axios
            .get('/admin/forms/'+this.comboDataSource+'/listDataSource')
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;

                });


    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            regexPattern : /(?<=\()(.*)(?=)\)/g,
            datafields: [
                { name: 'value' },
                { name: 'label' }
            ],
            source: this.getComboSource()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Result of the `axios` is this for some reason is converted to vue instances like so,

```
0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
length: 2
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

The value inside 0 is

```
label: "SS Sales Corportation"
value: 1
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get label: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set label: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get value: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set value: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object
```

If anyone is familiar with this, please I have two question.
1. Why is the return is not just js object?
2. When the data comes, how can I set it to the `JqxCombo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1st question* :

That’s a special property added by Vue, it’s part of the Reactivity system which allows Vue to track data changes and react to them, you could read more about it in the [official doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

*2nd question* :

When the data comes using `axios` call you could assign it to `source` property like :

```
getComboSource: function() {
  axios
    .get('/admin/forms/' + this.comboDataSource + '/listDataSource')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.source= response.data;//<-------

    });


}
```

and in your data Object you should initialize `source` as follows:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    regexPattern: /(?<=\()(.*)(?=)\)/g,
    datafields: [{
        name: 'value'
      },
      {
        name: 'label'
      }
    ],
    source:{}//<----
  }
}
```